# Balanced Payments tutorial in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, balanced-payments

Need to integrate **Balanced Payments** for transactions in my iPhone app. Is there any simple tutorial available for integrating Balanced Payments in iOS using RestKit.

Comment: check here https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ios

Comment: @Girish Thanks for the help, but need to implement the api using Rest kit. Do you know any way to integrate library.